# Increase size of the BSS section in the elf and other file formats

Tags: llvm, exe, elf, disassembly

I want to add a 4KB space to the bss section of an executable elf file. How can this be done?

If not bss section, can I increase the size of the data section or define a new data section
and initialize the region ?

If possible, can this be done with binary file formats other than elf ?

PS: I need this to add some extra instructions for instrumentation and saving the data in dedicated locations which have to be printed later.

Comment: You need to edit the linker script file to increase or decrease the size of mentioned sections. Have you looked the respective linker script file?

Comment: @GauravPathak we only have the binaries. We cannot fiddle with the compilation / linking process.

Comment: Are there any segments following `.bss`?

Comment: @yugr in all the binaries that we have tried like `/bin/dd`, `/bin/cp` and all of our test cases, `bss` section always has the highest starting address. This is one reason we were more focused in increasing its size. Is this true in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to add a 4KB space to the bss section of an executable elf file. How can this be done?

Assuming you want to do that to an *already linked* `ELF` executable, note that *sections* are not used *at all* by anything (other than perhaps debugging tools) after the link is done; you want to modify the corresponding *segment*.

What you are asking for is impossible in general, but *might* be possible for your particular executable. In particular, it should be possible if the `LOAD` segment "covering" the `.bss` section is the last one, or if there is an in-memory gap between that segment and the next `LOAD` segment.

If there is space (in memory) to extend the `LOAD` segment in question, then all you have to do is patch its program header's `.p_memsz` and increment it by 4096.

You would need to understand the output from `readelf -Wl a.out` in detail.

**Update:**

> assuming that bss occurs last, is there a tool to change .p_memsz of the last segment in a line or two ?

I don't know of any tool to do this, but it's pretty trivial: program headers are fixed sized table starting at file offset `ehdr->e_phoff`. The table contains `ehdr->e_phnum` records. You read each record until you find the last `PT_LOAD` segment, update the `.p_memsz` member, seek back and write the updated record on top of what was there.

The `libelf` or `elfio` libraries may (or may not) make writing this tool easier.

> I guess to make the elf conformant, we also need to change the section size of bss accordingly ?

No, you don't:

- there is no requirement that sizes of `.bss` and the load segment match
- in fact, there is no requirement that any sections are present at all,
- like I said, *nothing* cares about any sections after the binary is linked.

Comment: In all the elf binaries that we have tried `bss` section has the highest address, and in the load segments, it appears as the last section of the last load segment. Is this true in general ? (Any counter example is welcome).

Comment: I feel that the bss section is always at the end of last loaded segment because this segment can have an in-memory size greater than the segment size on disk to accommodate a bss section of any size (which could be huge). Is this correct?

Comment: @codeman48 It is probably true that the `.bss`-containing segment is nearly always the last one. I am sure _it's possible_ to link an executable where this would be false, but it probably rarely / ~never happens in practice.

Comment: assuming that bss occurs last, is there a tool to change `.p_memsz` of the last segment in a line or two ? I guess to make the elf conformant, we also need to change the section size of bss accordingly ?

Comment: He'd also need to update `__bss_end`.